# I have an .exe portable file and do't know how to decompile and edit it ( has .reloc .rsrc and .text extension files when extracted with 7zip )

Tags: debugging, windows-installer, exe

It is an executable that can open a specific ( and only ) type of files.

When opening the program, I choose "Open" and choose my file and immediately it requires a Key which, as I have found out, is given after purchasing a device that works with this software.

Just to mention - I don't have a device related to it, but I have a file that needs to be opened ( the software has 2 possibilities ,
 1st -  working via USB with the devices and
 2nd - simply opening files saved by the same soft on a different computer.

There are no different types of this software and the only thing I need to do is be able to read the content of the file.

I need to skip checking the 32 character key  (the key is not related to the file, just to the software. It is just being asked not after launching the program but only after choosing a file to be opened).

Please advice me for a method or soft to decompile this portable .exe and remove the Key checking, as I don't need and don't have the device.

Just need to open the file. Tried IDA and OlyDbg (debugger) to try to modify the content of the HEX but they cannot read any word. It is no illicit action by doing it, it is simply a non logical feature of the software itself.

Comment: What you're doing sounds questionably legal. If IDA and OllyDBG cannot disassemble the file for you, it likely intentionally obscured. If I were to do something like this, for educational purposes only, I'd use one of the disassemblers you already mentioned. You can always use a hex editor to modify the bytes in a file. Just be careful. Maybe try attaching the disassembler to the running process and see if you can modify RIP.

Comment: It's a list of names I was working with.Please tell me what RIP is (instead of rest in peace :D ) and your idea with the running process sounds promising, as the key is asked right after opening the file ( I even created an empty text file and changed extension to the one the soft is working with, and it asks for the key anyway. Yje key hasn't anything related to the file I need to read. How do I find out which bytes form this command to ask a KEY and remove it to simply open the file I need? Open in the decompiler after it starts asking the for key? Or what running process should I focus on?

Comment: Another question. Olly wouldn't be able to "start the file" it seems to be packed  (Microsoft Visual C# / Basic .NET ) PEiD tells me. How can I unpack it?

Comment: EDITȘ my portable .exe is managed assembly. I can only debug it when itțs running and only when JIT compiler produces code. I am running it, I am opening mt file, it starts asking for the key but anyway, the debugger isnțt able to open it. What am I missing?

Comment: RIP is the instruction pointer for x64 applications.

Comment: You can unpack the file manually using OllyDBG, I've done it with malware before. Install the OllyDump plugin. You'll want to look for instructions such as PUSHAD and POPAD when looking for the stub to the unpacked code.